# How to use fmincon with variable length vector and prevent user to select a value violating constraints?

Tags: matlab, variables, optimization, constants

First of all I have written the code whcih is confidential and cant represent it in quick way. Sorry for that.

I have an optimization problem where I can solve the question with fmincon in matlab.

But some of the variables should be chosen as constant. Thus, the variables should change into their values set by the user in objective function decreasing the variable number.

**Ex:**

```
f = Ax_1+Bx_2
```

if user set the `x_1=5` then it should be as;

```
f = A*5+Bx_1
```

Also I need that, if the user select some of the variables by himself, then if most/all of the parts of the constraints are violated by the input values, user should be prevented to set those values and forced to change them.

**Ex:**

if A/B = 2 and user input both A & B then it is  needed to be checked if this constraint is satisfied (This is the problem). If he set only one of them, then fmincon can solve for the other.

There are 20< constraints so how to check them. And how to change variables into constant values.

Thanks.

### Edit

```
x0 = [0 1 2 3]; %1x4

f = @obj(x) 5*x(1) + 8*x(2) +9*x(3) + 10*x(4);

fmmincon(f);


%constraints
c1 = x(1)/x(2) - 80;
c2 = x(1) / x(3) - 5;
```

As a first glance fmincon optimize the function and give 4 vraiables as x vector. But if user select `x(1) = 10` and `x(3) = 5` then function should be represented as;

```
f = @obj(x) 5*10 + 8*x(1) +9*5 + 10*x(2);
```

and `c2`  should be checked if user entered a correct set of parameter values for all kind of constraints if it is created by onlye those two(`x1` and `x3`);

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. You should at least edit your post to make it readable and post a little dummy example if you want to get any help at all

Comment: Actually I tried to give some dummy examples for both cases.

Comment: I don't see any MATLAB code in there

Comment: Because I couldn't imagine how to do that. All I know is, I need to change some variables into constants like 1, 2, 10 in a function and other variables should re_indexed maybe. End secondly, if the user set some variables as constant, the constraints only computed by those constants should be checked if user entered a proper set of constant for those parameters.

Comment: By the way I have written the code for non-dynamic case all variables is computed by the function. There is no functionality that allows user to select some parameters as constants.

Comment: Are you sure `c1 = x(1)/x(2) - 80;` defines a constraint? Also, the inequalities / equality constraints must be linear

Comment: These sets of parameters were given to me as constaints.m file which outputs two vectors as c and ceq.

Comment: Does it also output 2 matrices?

Comment: Those are nonlin constaints not linears. Thus there is nothing to do with matrices I guess.

Comment: Well then you'll not be able to do anything with `fmincon`..

Comment: Yes I need to change the objective function and constraints where variables necessary to be changed into constants. And detect constraints  composed of only with those changed parameters.

Comment: Nonono. In order to use `fmincon` you need a set of **linear** equalities / inequalities. As stated in the documentation

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/createoptimproblem.html in here non of the linear consts are used. And actualy I am dealing wtih the GUI thus I am not familiar with the math problem here that much. My colleagues said that it works currently if they set all parameters as optimization variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with the following code.

```
clear all, clc;
str = '0.000333*((x(1) - 80)/20) + 5*((x(2) - 20)/5) - 0.000333*((x(3) - 80)/20) + 5*((x(4) - 20)/5) - 0.000333*((x(5) - 80)/20) + 5*((x(6) - 20)/5)';

vals = [10 20];
idx = [1 0 0 0 1 0];

filter = find(idx);%find ids of constant vars

for i = 1:length(filter)

     f = ['x(' num2str(filter(i)) ')'];
    str = strrep(str, f, num2str(vals(i))); 
end

match = regexpi(str, '(x+\(\d*\))','match');

for i = 1:length(match)

    rep = ['x(' num2str(i) ')'];
    str = strrep(str, match{i}, rep);
end
```